# How can my C# Windows Runtime Component install the WebView2 Runtime?

Tags: c#, uwp, webview2, winrt-component

Pretty simple question.  I know how to find out if it's been installed.  But, if it hasn't....how do I install it?  All of the documentation appears to be geared towards C++ where you can just run Shell commands.  I also found something where you can use a FullTrustProcessLauncher but you have to modify the package manifest to get permission and, since this is a component, I can't do that.

Comment: What about making it a dependency in your nuget spec? I assume that is a thing.

Comment: @mxmissile - the way it works is that, as a C# component, I have to set a dependency on both the WinUI2 (latest pre-release) and the WebView2 NuGet packages.  But, they don't work without the extra step of installing the WebView2 Runtime Component (which is a ~100Mb download from Microsoft).  The good news is, that if another Application has already installed the Runtime, my component can use that install.